# Splitting a string with multiple spaces

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a string like

```
"first     middle  last"
```

with `String.split()`. But when i try to split it I get

```
String[] array = {"first","","","","middle","","last"}
```

I tried using `String.isEmpty()` to check for empty strings after I split them but I it doesn't work in android.  Here is my code:

```
String s = "First  Middle Last";
String[] array = s.split(" ");
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  //displays segmented strings here
}
```

I think there is a way to split it like this: `{"first","middle","last"}` but can't figure out how.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: YOURSTRING.split(/\s+/ig)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Since the argument to [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), you can look for one or more spaces (`" +"`) instead of just one space (`" "`).

```
String[] array = s.split(" +");
```

Comment: hmm i never thought about using just " +" i'm always more conventional using "\\s+". Good idea!

Comment: @Kevin, well, `\s` includes more than just spaces.

Comment: I also suggest to add trim() before split(): `s.trim().split(" +")` to handle cases like `"  first    middle    last    "`

Comment: I tried that in Chrome and it didn't work for me. Adjusting to be the following made it work: `String[] array = s.split(/\ +/);`

Comment: Where is the description of " +" or "\\s+"

Comment: I found the description of \s in Pattern, but I saw no mention of dealing with multiple white spaces by sticking the + on there.

Comment: @JohnnyCoder, look under ["Greedy quantifiers"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy).

Comment: @rid lol when i saw those i thought it was literally an X, not that X was just a variable

Comment: @AndreM This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: I am using ES6 in React. Strange, " +" not worked. I ended up doing this way: event.target.value.trim().split(' ').filter(ele => ele.length == 0 ? false : true)

Comment: @DanielC.Deng, the question is about Java, not JavaScript. These are two completely different languages. If you want to split a string in JavaScript by a regex, then you would use `split(/ +/)`, not `split(" +")` (JavaScript's [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function can take a string or a regex, and in your case you would use a regex). Still, the syntax of JavaScript is quite different from the syntax used in the question, I'm not sure what would make one think this has anything to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 28):

try using this `s.split("\\s+");`

Answer (score 14):

if you have a string like

```
String s = "This is a test string  This is the next part    This is the third part";
```

and want to get an array like

```
String[] sArray = { "This is a test string", "This is the next part", "This is the third part" }
```

you should try

```
String[] sArray = s.split("\\s{2,}");
```

The `{2,}` part defines that at least 2 and up to almost infinity whitespace characters are needed for the split to occur.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.

```
s.split(/\s+/)
```

```js
var foo = "first     middle  last";

console.log(foo.split(/\s+/));
```

Comment: it is java not javascript

Answer (score 3):

Since `split()` uses [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you can do something like `s.split("\\s+")` to set the split delimiter to be any number of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

How about using something that is provided out of the box by Android SDK.

```
TextUtils.split(stringToSplit, " +");
```

Comment: What's the reason of using Android SDK functions instead of a more portable code?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for koltin code

```
val str = "   fly me   to   the moon  "
println(str.trim().split(" +".toRegex()))

// output - [fly, me, to, the, moon]
```